# Comparing data against two worksheets and print matched values in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, printing, compare

I am new to the Excel VBA platform and am self-taught. I am working across 2 worksheets named 'Coupler Rotation Matrix' and 'Calculation Input Link' within the same workbook.

- 'Coupler Rotation Matrix' has data from columns C to DI (110 columns) and rows 4 to 1800.
- 'Calculation Input Link' has data in column M from rows 2 to 111.

I need to write a macro to achieve the following:

1. Compare values starting from C4 up to C184 ('Coupler Rotation Matrix' sheet) with the value in M2 ('Calculation Input Link' sheet)
2. If the value matches then I need the data to be printed under column C row 185 ('Coupler Rotation Matrix') if another value matches it should be printed in column C row 186 and so on.
3. Next I need to move to column D ('Coupler Rotation Matrix' sheet) and check the values D4 to D1804 against M3. If there is a match the data should be printed in D 185, 186, etc.
4. I am unsure how to print the matched values therefore I tried creating a new sheet to just print the matched values - however this seems to be not working.

The following is the code I came up with but on running it I am finding errors of various kinds.

```
Sub forloop()

Dim irow As Integer
Dim icolumn As Integer
Dim Value As Double
Dim checkvalue As Double


For irow = 1 To 110
   
   Worksheets("Coupler Rotation matrix").Columns(irow).Select
   
   For icolumn = 4 To 184
     
      Value = Worksheets("Coupler Rotation matrix").Rows(icolumn).Value
     

        Dim i As Integer
         For i = 2 To 111
            checkvalue = Columns("M" & i).Value
            If Value = checkvalue Then
           
            Sheets("Coupler Rotation Matrix").Columns(M & i).Copy 
            Sheets("sheet4").Columns(B & i).PasteSpecial

           End if

        Next i

   Next icolumn
   
Next irow

End Sub
```

Comment: What errors specifically are you running into?

Comment: Runtime error 1004; Runtime error 13 type mismatch error amongst others